# How to Clone a Git repository in Eclipse with non standard port on osx

Tags: eclipse, macos, git

My context:

My Git repository is on a Ubuntu Server where I changed the ssh port

On my client side (OS X) the syntax ssh host:port doesn't work

Using shell, the solution is simple: ssh host -p port

But, I'm using Eclipse and I need to clone my project from eclipse

When I used the standard port (22), the eclipse wizzard 'clone a git repository' was working fine but since I have changed the port, The wizzard failed:

I fill the following fields:

- Host
- Repository
- Path
- Protocol (ssh)
- Port
- user
- password

I see in Eclipse window that URI is created with the syntax:
ssh://user@host:port/repository
so, as this syntax doesn't work in shell, I suppose it is the reason

I try this workaround:
Create a host in /.ssh/config 
with an alias and my new port
And use the alias in the host field of Eclipse
It doesn't work and it seems Eclipse does not take in account my config file

After many google researches, I finally try asking a new question here

Many thanks for your help

Comment: I have the exactly same problem, the only difference is my client side is a Centos 6. But I'm trying to achieve the same, use a non standard port for ssh and clone (push, pull, etc) a git repo from eclipse. Using command line works perfect, but I need to do the same in Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0):

Having just spent 3 days beating my head on the wall about this, I'm gonna answer you even though I'm a few years too late to help probably.

I noticed on the firewall of my git server that Eclipse was hitting port 22 no matter what port I specified in the dialog.  After confirming I could manually connect with

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/git-privkey -p 3215 git@git.example.com
```

And you should get connected and welcomed, then disconnected.

I set up my `~/.ssh/config` file like so:

```
Host git.example.com
    Hostname git.example.com
    Port 3215
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git-privkey
```

It is important to have the `Host` value match the host that Eclipse will connect to, which will also match the `Hostname` value.  If you don't do this, the host-specific configuration won't take effect.

Now test by connecting with just

```
ssh git.example.com
```

And you should get connected and welcomed, then disconnected.

Now, in Eclipse, simply copy/paste the SSH URI and leave the default port 22 set.  Username should come in from the URI (default is `git`).